# google api (sheets) Request had insufficient authentication scopes

Tags: python, google-api, anaconda, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

i want to read an write data from a sheet, reading works fine but writing doesn't. i use all the scopes mentioned in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append

```
data_writer(1,1,1)
```

code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
# Setup the Sheets API
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'+"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"+"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
store = file.Storage('credentials.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = apiclient.discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

# Call the Sheets API
SPREADSHEET_ID = '1JwVOqtUCWBMm_O6esIb-9J4TgqAmMIdYm9sf5y-A7EM'
RANGE_NAME = 'Jokes!A:C'
# How the input data should be interpreted.
value_input_option = 'USER_ENTERED'  
# How the input data should be inserted.
insert_data_option = 'INSERT_ROWS' 

def data_reader():
    #reading data
    read = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID,range=RANGE_NAME).execute()
    #reading values
    values = read.get('values', [])
    if not values:
        print('No data found.')
    else:

        for row in values:
            print(row[2])
            continue
def data_writer(score,num_comments,mystring):
    value_range_body = {
        "score":score,
        "num_comments":num_comments,
        "joke":mystring
    }
    request = service.spreadsheets().values().append(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, range=RANGE_NAME, valueInputOption=value_input_option, insertDataOption=insert_data_option, body=value_range_body)
    response = request.execute()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SCOPES must be of type list

> SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

Side note: you have

> .../auth/drive

And

> .../auth/drive.file

/drive.file limits the API to work with only drive.file API but /drive opens up to all of the drive API. So you should pick one that fits your needs.

Side note 2: 
Based on the link you’ve provided, it mentions you need at least one of the API’s to work with spreadsheets, so you may not need all of them either.

Comment: They must review their documentation!

Comment: # If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle. https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python

Answer (score 1):

First off you should only need `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` as it gives full access to a users drive account including reading and writing sheets.

- list of [Sheet scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#sheetsv4)
- list of [drive scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#drivev3)

If you have already run your code once and authenticated your user then changed the scopes in your code.  Remember that you will need to run your code again and re-authenticate the user to gain the access granted by the new scopes.

Side note:

```
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'+"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"+"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
```

Is just going to be one long string you need to separate them with a space or as the other answer states use an array.

```
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets ' + "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file " + "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
```

Comment: so i activated the google drive api in console.developers.google.com, is this all i need to do to authenticate. i changed this line:   

    SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"

Comment: Yes that should be all you need to do to setup your client.  When you run your code your user will need to login with their login and password and consent to your accessing their google drive data.

Comment: it doesnt ask for a login so i guess i gave my consent. but it still doesn't work, it gives the same error message

Comment: It probably already has once you need to reset it now checkout store = file.Storage('credentials.json')

Comment: i did it manualy; https://myaccount.google.com/permissions?pli=1
then got myself new permission with the quickstart.py file found here https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python
where i changed the scope to "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
can i do this cleaner in the future?

Comment: # If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.